# MySQL Search features such as - and +

Tags: mysql, search

Lets say I'm searching the field `title`, how would I set it up so you could use + and - on keywords on an SQL level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [Full-text searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html), especially [boolean searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Slightly modified example from the manual:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title) 
AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

you don't even need to create a `FULLTEXT` index for these kinds of searches but it is very recommended.